# Send Object (Class) from C# Client to Java Server over TCP

Tags: java, c#, serialization, tcp

i'm trying to send an object from c# to java over a TCP connection but it does not work. Java tell me there is an error and i don't know why

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C3F786D
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ClientThread.run(ClientThread.java:34)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I googled it already but found no precise answer for my problem. I have serialized my c# class with and xml serializer. I've found the code on the internet.

Here is the c# code

```
        var cmd = new Command();
        cmd.setType(5);

        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Command));

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(memoryStream, cmd);
        }

        String sendMsg = message + ";";
        try
        {
            if (tcp_stream.CanWrite)
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(tcp_stream, cmd);
            }
            tcp_stream.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error..... " + exception);
        }
```

And the Java server code is

```
try {

    ObjectOutputStream sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream sInput = new ObjectInputStream(
    socket.getInputStream());
    this.message = (Message) sInput.readObject();
    System.out.println("MessageType: " + this.message.getType());
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Can not get message. " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
    break;
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks for any answers.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java binary serialization and .NET XML serialization are not compatible with each other. Java binary serialization is compatible with itself and that is pretty much it. You need to pick a common format which can be serialized and deserialized by both. Some examples might include some flavor of XML or JSON or BSON, Google Protobuf, etc.